# In Windows 8.1 XAML/C# app, how can I style the buttons precisely?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm new to Windows 8.1 development, so forgive me if the answer to this is obvious, but I've been beating on this for awhile, and can't get it to work.  Here's the situation:

I made a UserControl in order to style a button as well as adding additional functionality to it.  Here's the code for that:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyCalculator.CalculatorButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyCalculator"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
>
    <!-- THIS GRID TAKES UP THE WHOLE WIDTH AND HEIGHT -->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- THIS BUTTON TAKES UP THE WHOLE SIZE OF THE GRID -->
        <Button 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            BorderBrush="Blue"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Background="AliceBlue"
            Padding="0"
            Content="How can I make this bigger?"
            Foreground="Blue"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
        />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's what it looks like in the designer:
[image: The Grid takes up the whole space, and the Button takes up the whole space, but the Button's color and border are clearly much smaller]

You'll notice that the Button appears to be centered both horizontally and vertically, and is rather small.  However, when I click into the Button in the code, the entire size of the Grid (which takes up the whole 400 x 300 area in the designer) is filled by the Button.

So the Button is filling the Grid, which is filling the area.  But the Border and Background of the Button is super-small, in the middle of the Button.  Worse yet, it doesn't even stretch to contain the text.  This is obviously not the desired look and feel.

What am I *trying* to get it to do?  I want the AliceBlue button background to fill the entire Grid, which fills the entire 400 x 300 area.  I'd like the 'How can I make this bigger?' blue Content string centered vertically and horizontally in the big swath of AliceBlue-ness that will result.

I've tried innumerable combinations of specifications of Margin, Padding, Height, Width, and other attributes on the Grid and on the Button.  Nothing has affected the size or placement of the AliceBlue area of the Button.

Clearly I'm missing something.  Can anyone help me understand what that is, and how I can format my button (or the UserControl in general) to look the way I want it to?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but here's a couple of thoughts... Can you include your Grid.RowDefinitions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions? Have you tried assigning Grid.Row="0" and Grid.Column="0" on your Button so that it knows it is supposed to be in that spot?

Comment: "I created a usercontrol to style a button"... Really the wrong approach in WPF, you should create a style and use the root button type and apply the style to it.

Comment: Hi @RonBeyer, thanks for the input.  First, I'm in WinRT and not WPF, so I don't know if that changes anything (I know there are some significant differences between the platforms).  Second, I did create a style and use the root button type and apply the style to it, but that didn't work in the context of my actual Page, so to isolate the parts I'm trying to figure out, I created a UserControl so I could just iterate on this one thing specifically.  Also, in the end, it'll be a lot more involved than just a Button, so a custom UserControl seemed like the best way to go.

Comment: Hi @KennyWyland, I did have those in there originally (all three pieces you mentioned), but I went for brevity in the example so there was less to dig through.  I'll edit the post to add those back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a string value to the Content property have you tried to put in a TextBlock child element?  This might give you more control  Hi.  Button has HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment that you can set.  And then you can modify the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment of the child TextBlock inside the button independently.

Comment: The solution (which I could have sworn someone else posted here, but I guess not?) ended up being that Button has HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment properties and setting those to Stretch did what I needed it to do.  There wasn't a need to put a TextBlock in the Button.Content per se.  But thanks for the answer, I've marked it as correct because I think it would work even though it's not exactly what I ended up going with.